# Why absolute positioning is overlapping text from second div

Tags: css, tailwind-css

i am trying to set text over image, my text is showing on image using absolute positioning but text from the below div is overlapped by the image.

Why text is coming under image, text should show below image.

[**WORKING CODE**](https://play.tailwindcss.com/A899xJ6CkQ)

```
<div class="absolute bg-cover w-full object-fill">
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/16/9c/f8/169cf8b4b0fc8c7411662da2eab90c2a.jpg" alt="">
<div class="absolute  bottom-0 text-white font-bold text-3xl w-full text-center" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);">
  THIS SECTION
</div>
</div>

 <div class=" text-4xl flex items-center justify-center bg-gradient-to-br from-ispmain to-yellow-400  text-white  font-bold mx-auto" >
            WELCOME TO THIS SECTION
        </div>
        <section class="bg-white md:ml-8 md:mr-8 px-4 py-4 ">  
        <div class="flex flex-col md:flex-row px-8 my-4 ">
        <div class="flex flex-wrap text-lg md:w-3/5 leading-relaxed md:order-first">
          <p class="fade text-justify">
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate sit et omnis id vitae vel tenetur veniam tempora nam officia consequuntur dignissimos dolorem corrupti molestiae similique ipsam, qui suscipit veritatis?
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi, ipsum odio! Culpa dolorum sit laborum velit aut earum nostrum et quam? Placeat asperiores officiis reprehenderit! Reiciendis voluptatibus nisi illo doloremque.
       Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati maiores magni, omnis tempora debitis fuga consequuntur delectus soluta quae, commodi est itaque placeat totam voluptatum laboriosam quidem mollitia ex eveniet.
 </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because you're setting the wrapper of the image and the text as an `absolute` position. I have set the wrapper to position `relative` and it does what you need. See the html below:

```
<div class="relative bg-cover w-full object-fill">
  <img src="your img url here" alt="">
<div class="absolute  bottom-0 text-white font-bold text-3xl w-full text-center" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);">
  THIS SECTION
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: if this was a help for you and solved your issue, please could you mark it as the correct answer?